# Variable bit length lossy floating point compression

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, compression

I am implementing a new compression algorithm for the weights of a neural network for the [Leela Chess project](http://lczero.org). the weights are roughly `100Mb` of `float32`s which I want to compress as small as possible. Error tolerance for this application is `2^-17`, so lossy compression is clearly the right answer here. All of the weights are between -5 and 5, but 99.995% are in (-.25,.25) and most reasonably closely clumped around zero.

The basic idea with this algorithm is to turn floats into integer multiples of the error tolerance, and then use a utf-8 inspired encoding to represent small values with only 1 byte.

```
import numpy as np
import bz2
def compress(in_path, out_path):
    with open(in_path, 'rb') as array:
        net = np.fromfile(in_path, dtype=np.float32)

    # Quantize
    net = np.asarray(net * 2**17, np.int32)

    # Zigzag encode
    net = (net >> 31) ^ (net << 1)

    # To variable length
    result = np.zeros(len(net)*3, dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(3):
        big = (net >= 128) << 7
        result[i::3] = (net % 128) + big
        net >>= 7

    # Delete non-essential indices
    zeroes = np.where(result == 0)[0]
    zeroes = zeroes[np.where(zeroes % 3 != 0)]
    result = np.delete(result, zeroes)

    with bz2.open(out_path, 'wb') as out:
        out.write(result.tobytes())
def decompress(in_path, out_path):
    with bz2.open(in_path, 'rb') as array:
        result = np.frombuffer(array.read(), dtype=np.uint8)

    start_inds = np.where(result<128)[0]
    not_zeroed = np.ones(len(start_inds), dtype=np.bool)

    # append zeroe so loop doesn't go out of bounds
    result = np.append(result, np.zeros(4, dtype=np.uint8))

    # Get back fixed length from variable length
    net = np.zeros(len(start_inds), dtype=np.uint32)
    for i in range(3):
        change = (result[start_inds] % 128) * not_zeroed
        net[np.where(not_zeroed)[0]] *= 128
        net += change
        start_inds += 1
        not_zeroed &= result[start_inds] >= 128

    # Zigzag decode
    net = (net >> 1) ^ -(net & 1)
    print(np.mean(net))

    # Un-quantize
    net = np.asarray(net, np.float32)
    net /= 2**17

    with open(out_path, 'wb') as out:
        out.write(version)
        out.write(net.tobytes())

compress('diff.hex','diff.bz2')
decompress('diff.bz2','round.hex')
```

The main type of advice I'm looking for is algorithm and performance advice, but ways to make the code readable are always nice.

Comment: Did you confirm that the variable length encoding is an improvement over feeding the zigzag directly into bz2?

Comment: no, but I have compared it to just quantizing and zipping. Is zigzag without vle likely to compress better than just zipping?

Comment: You can test different combinations to know for sure. Zigzag increases the number of zero bytes, and a general purpose compressor like bz2 should be able to exploit that, at least to some degree.

Comment: The difference in scales of your values makes me wonder if using sign(weight) * log(weight) might be more compressible since it should make the overall distribution of weights more uniform. I guess quantization using percentiles would work just as well though.

Comment: It's actually exactly the opposite. The more uniform you make the distribution, the less compressible it is.